# OpenMP overhead takes large percentage of running time

Tags: c++, openmp

I used openMP to parallelize a for loop:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < selections.size(); ++i) {
        foo(selections[i]);
    }
```

And I used Google profiler and it shows omp_get_num_procs takes large percentage of my cpu:

```
 10554  97.8%  97.8%    10554  97.8% omp_get_num_procs
    66   0.6%  98.4%       85   0.8% __find (inline)
```

Computer is octa core and I set the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS=8`. How can I improve this?

Comment: Is `foo()` doing anything useful?  Until it does, 100% has to be distributed *somewhere*.

Comment: It does a lot of calculations with a vector, and this part is just a part of a program . THe entire program is over 1k lines

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I never call that function...

Comment: Ye but the compiler need to know how many threads are set for the parallel loop try to set a variable which contains the number of your threads. Put it explicitly in the code and add `num_threads(var)` at the end of the pragma omp parallel

Comment: What does each column in the profile show? Which operating system are you running? Which compiler suite?

Comment: Without knowing more about your program it's hard to help. How many times are you repeating your test? How much work does `foo()` do? Is the compiler optimizing `foo()` away because it has no side effects? What is selections.size()?

Comment: It seems that is not so much that `omp_get_num_procs` is slow, but that the profiler misidentifies all calls to OpenMP as `omp_get_num_procs`: http://codearcana.com/posts/2013/05/10/why-is-omp_get_num_procs-so-slow.html